# How can I access my files, similar to windows' " My Computer"?

Tags: windows, files

How could i see my files in Ubuntu? In windows, I see my files in different partition, so in Ubuntu can i see files like windows ?

Comment: What is your question *really* asking? It is very hard to tell in its current state.

Comment: Are you dual booting, or trying to access files that you have created in Windows from a USB drive? Are you using Unity?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu you use the `nautilus` file browser. I'm assuming you have installed Ubuntu 11.10. If you have, and you are using Unity, you can browse your files easily by clicking on the "Home Folder" icon in the launcher.

Nautilus is easy to use, and you should be able to get accustomed to it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access your files from Ubuntu, then you may try one of these methods:

- Go to "Filesystem" (`/`) and open `/media/nameofdisk`.
- Open the drive/partition from the launcher (if it shows up)
- Open the drive/partition from `/windows` (if you have chosen to set it up to point to that folder).
- Open the drive/partition from the Disk Utility.

  - This program can be found in the Dash (just type Disk Utility).